# How to to rout to another action and render the second one partially too?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have partial view renders itself inside a JQuery popup.

```
<div id="enumsDialog" class="dialog">
@Html.Action("List", "Enumeration")
</div>
```

In this view, I have an action link to another view.

The question is there a way to let the second view renders in the same popup? I mean keep the rendering partially and without closing the popup.

I read about `Ajax.BeginForm()`, but it causes a redirecting to the second view.

Answer (score 0):

You can render the first action inside an IFRAME.

Then you can render the new one with a simple @Html.Action and it will render in the same IFRAME.